# Apache Camel exclude option not working together with GenericFileFilter

Tags: java, apache-camel

Apache Camel include, exclude options not working together with GenericFileFilter

I have tried with include, exclude options using camel route url and is working fine.

I also tried GenericFileFilter implementation and is working fine.
Both are working individually but not together.

Apache Camel exclude option not working together with GenericFileFilter

Filter #1:

I would like to do a database operation when I find a duplicate file.
So this logic I implemented in overridden accept method by extending GenericFileFilter class.

Filter #2:

Also, I do not want get the *.JPG image files and get only say *.xml files.
So I have added the File2 options in the Route URL with below options

```
antInclude=*.xml&antExclude=*.jpg
```

or

```
include=.*\\.xml$&exclude=.*\\.jpg$
```

Question:

- when I use only "Filter#1" camel is processing files as expected.

and

- when I use only "Filter#2" camel is processing files as expected.

But, when I use both Filter#1 and Filter#2 together, camel is not considering include or exclude uri options and is not working as expected.

I referred to the below apache camel URL:

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

Also I referred to GenericFileFilter API.

But no luck.

Comment: Can someone let me know what I am missing? or provide an alternative way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use either include/exclude or the ANT style variation, and not mix both of them together.

Comment: How about using both GenericFileFilter in combination with include/exclude?

Comment: The GenericFileFilter takes precedence. You can look in the source code (the consumer)